# JAWS screen reader announcing complete text when dropdown is opening

Tags: internet-explorer, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

When we are opening a menu dropdown in IE jaws it is announcing the text of the heading which is present in another div. 
Sample app has been deployed at following location -https://jawsaccessibility.herokuapp.com/index.html

Steps to replicate

1. Open Url in IE
2. Start JAWS
3. Click on blank area in ui(grey color)
4. Press tab and then enter to open dropdown

Output - "Nam non metus diam........"  text will be announced with dropdown text.

Expected - only dropdown text should have been announced

Comment: Created issue on jaws github - https://github.com/FreedomScientific/VFO-standards-support/issues/90

Comment: Seems like Issue is with when focus moves from one element to another. For example when we move from div 1 to div 2 and div 2 is parallel to div 1 or somewhere else then jaws will announce the complete text of div 2 parent which has tabindex.

Comment: I have Jaws 2018 and IE11 under Windows 10 18.03 x64, it doesn't happen with me Jaws correctly says just "dropdown text"..

Comment: Have you checked in the attached sample url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[stevefaulkner](https://github.com/stevefaulkner) commented 3 days ago  in the following github issue - https://github.com/FreedomScientific/VFO-standards-support/issues/90

This is due to an issue with how IE represents elements in the accessibility tree. When an element has a tabindex then it is included in the accessibility tree and the accessible name for that element is the child text, unless there is some other source for the accessible name provided. In the test case
 is presented as a grouping object in the accessibility tree with an accessible name of "Nam non metus diam. Mauris vehicula ac lectus eu pharetra" and is announced when the dropdown button receives focus.

Try adding aria-label="" (empty label) to the div. This provides an alternative 'null' label for the div and resolves the problem.